# REST File upload with resume and metadata support

Tags: rest, api, upload

I want to implement a REST API for file upload, which has the following requirements:

1. Support for resumable and chunked uploads
2. Support for adding and editing metadata after upload, like tags or descriptions
3. Be resource friendly, so uploads should use raw data, i.e. no encoding and / or encapsulation

So, requirements 1) and 3) already rule out use of multipart forms (I don't like this approach anyways).

I already have a working solution to satisfy requirement 1), by issuing a `POST` request first, which transmits `fileName`, `fileSize` and `fileModification` date as JSON. The upload module then creates a temporary file (if none exists!) and responds with a `206`, containing an upload token in the header, which in turn is a hash created over the data sent in the `POST`. This token has to be used for the actual upload. The response also contains a byte range which instructs the client what part of the file it has to upload. The advantage is that by this way, it is detectable if a former partial upload already exists - the trick is to name the temporary file the same as the token. So the byte range might also start with another value than `0-`. All the user has to do to resume an interupted upload is to upload the same file again!

The actual upload is done via `PUT`, with the message body only containing the raw binary data. The response then returns the metadata of the created file as JSON, *or* responds with another `206` containing an updated byte range header if the upload is still incomplete. So by this way, also chunked uploads are possible. All in all I like this solution and it works well. At least I see no other way to implement resumable uploads without a 2 stage approach.

Now, my problem is to make this truly "RESTish".

Lets say we have a collection named `/files` where I want to upload files. Of course, `POST /files` seems to be the natural way to do so. But then, we would have a subsequent `PUT` to the *same collection* which is of course not REST compatible in my eyes. Next approach would be that the initial `POST` returns a new URL that points to the final resource: `/files/{fileId}`and the subsequent `PUT`(s) write to this resource instead.

That feels more "RESTish", but is not as straightforward and then it may be possible that there are incomplete file resources floating around when upload is not completed. I think the actual resource should only be created if the upload is  complete. Furthermore, if I want to update / add metadata later on, that would be a `PUT` to the same resource, but the request itself would be quite different. Hmmm.

I could change the `PUT` to a `POST`, so the upload would consist of multiple `POST`s but this smells fishy as well.

I also thought of splitting the resource in two subresources, like `/files/{fileId}/metadata` and `/files/{fileId}/binary` but this feels a bit "overengineered" and also requires the file resource to be created before the upload is complete.

Any ideas how to solve this in a better way?